# How to append suffix to all string matched regular expression in unix

Tags: unix, command-line, sed

I need to replace all occurrences of string in specific format (in my case colon followed by some number) with same string with suffix in a file, like this:

```
:123456 -> :123456_suffix
```

Is there a way to do it with sed or other unix command-line tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sed should do that:

```sh
sed -i~ -e 's/:\([0-9]\{1,\}\)/:\1_suffix/g' file
                ^  ^  ^      ^   ^        ^
                |  |  |      |   |        |
    start capture  |  |    end   |  globally, i.e. not just the first
    group          |  | capture  |              occurrence on a line
           any digit  |          the first capture
                 one or          group contents
                 more times
```

If `-i` is not supported, just create a new file and replace the old one:

```sh
sed ... > newfile
mv oldfile oldfile~ # a backup
mv newfile oldfile
```

Comment: Plus one for a portable solution!

Answer (score 2):

use sed,

```
sed 's/\(:[0-9]\+\)/\1_suffix/g' file
```

add `-i` modifier , if you want to do an in-place edit.